# Is there a @retval equivalent for out parameters in Doxygen? (C/C++)

Tags: c++, c, doxygen

Doxygen's `@retval` provides a clear way to document multiple return values:

```
/**
 * Do the thing to the other thing.
 *
 * @param[in] other_thing The thing to do it to.
 *
 * @retval STATUS_OK on success.
 * @retval STATUS_BAD_ARGS if the other thing wasn't right.
 * @retval STATUS_TIMED_OUT if the thing timed out.
 */
status_t do_the_thing(thing_t other_thing);
```

But what if that status is returned via an output parameter? Is there a convention for documenting those values?

```
/**
 * Do a couple things to the other thing.
 *
 * @param[in] other_thing The thing to do it to.
 * @param[out] out_status_1 The status of the first thing done.
 * @param[out] out_status_2 The status of the second thing done.
 */
void do_a_couple_things(
    thing_t other_thing, status_t *out_status_1, status_t *out_status_2);
```

Currently we'll say something like

```
/**
 * ...
 * @param[out] out_status_1 The status of the first thing done.
 *     - STATUS_OK on success.
 *     - STATUS_BAD_ARGS if the other thing wasn't right.
 *     - STATUS_TIMED_OUT if the first thing timed out.
 * @param[out] out_status_2 The status of the second thing done.
 *     - STATUS_OK on success.
 *     - STATUS_NOT_FOUND if the thing wasn't in the second thing index.
 *     - STATUS_NO_MEMORY if there wasn't enough space for the thing.
 */
```

but it'd be really nice to have something more structured.

Even if it's not a builtin command, would it be possible to define a command like `@paramval` that binds to the most-recent `@param`? E.g.,

```
/**
 * ...
 * @param[out] out_status_1 The status of the first thing done.
 *   @paramval STATUS_OK on success.
 *   @paramval STATUS_BAD_ARGS if the other thing wasn't right.
 *   @paramval STATUS_TIMED_OUT if the first thing timed out.
 * @param[out] out_status_2 The status of the second thing done.
 *   @paramval STATUS_OK on success.
 *   @paramval STATUS_NOT_FOUND if the thing wasn't in the second thing index.
 *   @paramval STATUS_NO_MEMORY if there wasn't enough space for the thing.
 */
```

I was hoping to get some inspiration from the implementation of `@parblock`, but it looks like it's a built-in command with special internal support. I didn't see an obvious way to define a custom command that binds to the most-recent `@param`.

Comment: Is this really specific to out parameters?  Input parameters can have enumerated type just as easily.

Comment: What was the result when you asked on one of the Doxygen forums?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews That assumes that I asked on a Doxygen forum, which I didn't consider looking for. I'll see if they have any suggestions.

Comment: Asked in the Doxygen forum at https://sourceforge.net/p/doxygen/discussion/130994/thread/55e2ce1bfd/; I'll update this question if I hear back.

Comment: There is no equivalent in doxygen of `@retval` for `param`, but you could emulate something by using lists and mention each value on a new line  and start it with a minus sign (to start a list item).

Comment: I never got an answer from the Doxygen forum, so we're sticking with using bulleted lists.

Comment: The way I understand the need, @param should just refer to an ENUM, and that's it. The documentation of the ENUM describes each value. In some "extreme" case, just explain which subset of the values is allowed, and why. For something more complicated, document the values in the content of the function (switch / case statement, if-else-if statements... or whatever you are using.)